# Why does my <a> and <b> if conditional not execture when a and b are both True?

Tags: python, if-statement, wxpython, wxwidgets

EDIT: It was a typo on my part. I couldn't see the lack of parantheses after GetEventObject for some reason.

Code:

```
   def onKeyDown(self, event):
        ESC_list = [self.topic_control,self.search_control]
        print event.GetEventObject() in ESC_list
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        print keycode == wx.WXK_ESCAPE
        if keycode == wx.WXK_ESCAPE and event.GetEventObject in ESC_list:
            print "fire"
            self.onExit(event)
        event.Skip()
```

When I run tests where both print statements give me "True" the if conditional doesn't execute. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a pair of parentheses:

```
if keycode == wx.WXK_ESCAPE and event.GetEventObject() in ESC_list:
#                                                   ^^ HERE
```

Your current code is syntactically valid, but has different semantics. It checks whether the function object itself -- and not the result of calling the function -- is present in `ESC_list`.

Comment: Thanks. I spotted that myself just before I came to check for answers.